# Tensorflow C++ set GPU memory fraction and allow growth

Tags: c++, tensorflow, gpu

I want to set the `GPU memory fraction` and `allow growth` options as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth) for python, but in C++. Is this the correct way of doing this? I am especially not sure about the `set_allocated_gpu_options` line (what does 'allocated' mean in this case, nothing is allocated yet).

```
tensorflow::Session *session = nullptr;
tensorflow::SessionOptions sessionOptions;
tensorflow::GPUOptions gpuOptions;
gpuOptions.set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(0.2);
gpuOptions.set_allow_growth(true);
sessionOptions.config.set_allocated_gpu_options(&gpuOptions);
tensorflow::Status status = tensorflow::NewSession(sessionOptions, &session);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to do exactly the same and this is how I do it in my project:

```
auto options = tensorflow::SessionOptions();
options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(0.2);
options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allow_growth(true);
tensorflow::Status status = tensorflow::NewSession(options, &session);
```

The `_allocated` part of `set` has to do with protobuf's memory management. If you `set` the options, it will expect an object that was dynamically allocated and it will take ownership over it (and delete it when appropriate). Your code won't work, because you're passing an address to a local variable that will get destroyed when you exit the code block.

Instead, if you access the existing instance of `GpuOptions` via `mutable_gpu_options()` you get a pointer to the object that you can use to edit directly that instance (i.e., no need for allocating your own)